# NightNight in Swift to change themes, problem with attributedText

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, themes, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently experimenting with [NightNight](https://github.com/Draveness/NightNight), an easy-to-use library to add light and dark themes to an app. I recommend looking into it if you are interested in adding two themes to your app.

That being said, it works like a charm. It is not fully supported yet, e.g. I am missing the ability to set the `shadowImage` of a `UITabBarController` to change the "top border" or separator, but I guess I can add this later by diving into the source.

One problem I am facing now, is that I am unable to change the color of `attributedText` of a `UITextView`. I definitely need to use the `attributedText` property because I want to add `lineHeightMultiple`. I got everything to work, but the color does not change when I switch between themes.

The `UITextView` is part of a `UICollectionViewCell`, so it is reused. Whenever I restart the app or start scrolling in the `UICollectionView`, the text is updated (sometimes - because of the reuse, it sometimes does not update when the cell remains visible on screen). It feels to me like I need to update or reload something else in order to get this library to work as I need.

Currently I set up my TextView like this:

```
let customTextViewStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
customTextViewStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.2

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is the text that will be shown inside the TextView")

attributedString.setMixedAttributes([NNForegroundColorAttributeName: MixedColor(normal: lightCustomTextViewFontColor, night: darkCustomTextViewFontColor)], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: customTextViewStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: normalFontSize), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

customTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Below is a fragment of the source file from [NightNight](https://github.com/Draveness/NightNight), which is called NSMutableAttributedString, where an observer is added:

```
public extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    fileprivate struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var mixedAttrsKey = "mixedAttrs"
    }

    fileprivate var mixedAttrs: [String: [NSRange: MixedColor]] {
        get {
            if let dict = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.mixedAttrsKey) as? [String : [NSRange : MixedColor]] {
                return dict
            }
            self.mixedAttrs = [:]

            MixedColorAttributeNames.forEach { (mixed) in
                self.mixedAttrs[mixed] = [:]
            }

            return self.mixedAttrs
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.mixedAttrsKey, newValue as AnyObject, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

            addNightObserver(#selector(_updateTitleAttributes))
        }
    }
}
```

Then _updateTitleAttributes looks like this:

```
@objc func _updateTitleAttributes() {

    MixedColorAttributeNamesDictionary.forEach { (mixed, normal) in
        if let foregroundColorDictionary = mixedAttrs[mixed] {
            foregroundColorDictionary.forEach({ (range, mixedColor) in
                self.addAttribute(normal, value: mixedColor.unfold(), range: range)
            })
        }

    }
}
```

I would highly appreciate a solution to this issue, as I myself am unable to figure it out. Does it have something to do with the source - e.g. does it not update properly? Does it have something to do with my `UICollectionViewCell`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you only use `attributedText` property on your `textView` and not mixing usage of `text` and `attributedText`. If that's not an issue try to reset text in your cell class in `prepareForReuse` method. `myTextView.attributedText = nil`

Comment: Both don't work. However, I will continue using prepareForReuse on my `UITextView` as well, so thanks for the heads up on that. I have a working solution right now but it's not as neat as I would want it to be: I add an observer for the notification that changes the theme (NightNightThemeChangeNotification). Next, in the function paired to it, I get all `.visibleCells`, run them in a for loop and add the attributes again. This works, but it is probably not the best solution. If nothing better comes up, I'll add this solution as an answer so others can learn from it.